# single app is support more platform android version

Tags: android, version, platform

how is support all platform version on my single android app.i have created one app .
this is androidmanifest.xml file for this app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.androidhive" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".CustomizedListView" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SingleMenuItemActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity android:name=".InsertionExample" android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

here i have used uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"....so this app is successfully worked on android 2.2 device..but i wish to support all version on this app..how can i develop this.please help me..give ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />` , so your application works on Api Greater than 2.2 , but not less that 2.2 (Api 8).

If you want your application works less than android 2.2 then set minSdkVersion to as per your requirement.

Comment: ok fine..if i have to run the app on my device 4.1 means that 4.1 device is support in this app..it is corretc

Comment: @user1575906 your app is supports 4.1 . It suppots greater than 2.2 upto latest version

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer" 
      android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
      android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

And also see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

This is enough. Your app will support device which is having 2.2 and above. And, if you set your version in manifest file like -

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
    android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

Your app will work with above integer(version) based. For example -

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="8"
    android:maxSdkVersion="11" />
```

Your app will support from android device 1.6 upto 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You should always target the latest version of Android

```
uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="15"
```

Designing you app around that last version is also a good idea. ActionBarShelock is a library that will help you in order to use the ActionBar for all Android versions.
You should NOT use

```
android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

it was useful when Android 3.0 was introduced since it allowed to get some time to adapt your app to tablets but you should no longer rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

you may use like this in Your Manifest

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"/>
```

and also below depending on the requirement

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
 android:required="false" />
```